# Magento 2, passing data from phtml to observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer, quoteitem

Through `sales_quote_item_save_before` event I'm trying to fill the custom column added to `quote_item` table.The value of this field is based on input text field in below file. Using below observer, I could not make it work. How can pass the input value?

in **MyVendor/MyModule/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/items/grid.phtml**

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom-field" id="custom-field" title="custom-field" class="input-text"/>
```

**Observer**

```
$quoteItem = $observer->getEvent()->getItem();
if (isset($_POST['custom-field'])) {
    $value = $_POST['custom-field'];
}else{
    $value = "n/a";
}

$quoteItem->setCustom($value);
```

Comment: Have you checked which value return by $_POST before if condition?

Comment: Yes, In  $this->_log->debug($value); I got the n/a

Comment: Not i am talking about $_POST which value return?

Comment: It returns "Notice: Undefined index..."